# Counting the Number of Logins

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to count the total number of logins per day from mysql database.

I have implemented the query as shown below:

```
$query = "SELECT  DATE(login_date_time) AS 'Date', COUNT(DISTINCT pin) AS 
'PIN' FROM logged_users GROUP BY  DATE(login_date_time)";

 $result = $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

I would like to output in a tabular format? I used the below code but not working:

```
<?php echo $row['pin']; ?>
```

I want to output the date and the number of logins per date in a table.
Kindly assist.

Comment: so, what is your problem ?

Comment: Try looping through the array?

Comment: @Ravi...How do i output it to my page for viewers to see?

Comment: Should be `COUNT(DISTINCT pin) AS pin`, unquoted and lowercased. Try that.

Comment: did you try this ? `<?php echo $row['PIN']; ?>`

Comment: Pls view a sample : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0ce2/1/0

Comment: what is the current output and your expected ?

Comment: is there backticks I hope `AS 'PIN'` ?

Comment: @Ravi...the current output is blank...i want it to display in a tabular format with headers Date, Number of logins......output should come out with the date and say 20 logins

Comment: @Danny...I want to output the date and the number of logins per date

Comment: You will need to loop through the results, outputting each row in the form you want. The code you show only fetches one row. But your column name in your echo statement isn't in the results. Your column name is PIN, not pin.

Comment: @SloanThrasher..please give me an example thanks